# $p$-group of odd order with all proper subgroups cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

If $p$ is an odd prime and $G$ is a group of order $p^r$, with $r\ge 3$, such that all proper subgroups of $G$ are cyclic, then is $G$ cyclic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is true. Apply induction on $r$. For $r=3$ the claim holds since there are three types of abelian groups and two extraspecials to check. All these contain subgroups isomorphic to $C_p \times C_p$, except of course $C_{p^3}$.

Now suppose $r>3$. The inductive hypothesis tells you that all maximal subgroups of the group must be cyclic. Perhaps there is an easier way to finish off the problem, but one way is [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_p-groups_with_cyclic_maximal_subgroup).

Certainly $C_{p^{r-1}} \times C_p$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $C_p \times C_p$. As per this standard classification of $p$-groups with a cyclic maximal subgroup in the link, it suffices to show that the group

$$M_r(p) = \left\langle x, y : x^{p^{r-1}} = y^p = 1, x^y = x^{1+p^{r-2}} \right\rangle$$

contains a $C_p \times C_p$ subgroup. Take $H = \left\langle x^p,y \right\rangle \cong C_{p^{r-2}} \times C_p$ (do you see why?) and consider an appropriate subgroup of $H$.